# XML parser returns NoneType

Tags: python, elementtree

I am trying to parse below XML format using the ElementTree XML in Python, but I get "member" as None, when I use `.text` it gives attribute error

```
<address-group>
  <entry name="TBR">
    <static>
      <member>TBR1-1.1.1.1_21</member>
       <member>TBR2-2.2.2.2_24</member>
      <member>TBR3-3.3.3.3_21</member>
      <member>TBR4-4.4.4.4_24</member>
    </static>
   </entry>
<address-group>
```

Here is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("addrgrp.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
tag = root.tag
print (tag)
attr = root.attrib

for entries in root.findall("entry"):
    name = entries.get('name')
    print (name)
    ip = entries.find('static')
    print (ip)
    for mem in ip.findall('member'):
        member = mem.find('member')
        print (member)
```

Comment: What  do you  want to do?  I mean  - what is the information you want to collect from the XML doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below aggregate the members of each entry by entry name

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pprint

XML = '''

<address-group>
  <entry name="TBR1">
    <static>
      <member>TBR1-1.1.1.1_21</member>
       <member>TBR2-2.2.2.2_24</member>
      <member>TBR3-3.3.3.3_21</member>
      <member>TBR4-4.4.4.4_24</member>
    </static>
   </entry>
   <entry name="TBR2">
    <static>
      <member>TBR1-4.1.1.1_21</member>
       <member>TBR2-4.2.2.2_24</member>
      <member>TBR3-4.3.3.3_21</member>
      <member>TBR4-9.4.4.4_24</member>
    </static>
   </entry>
</address-group>'''

root = ET.fromstring(XML)
data_by_entry = {}
entries = root.findall('.//entry')
for entry in entries:
    data_by_entry[entry.attrib['name']] = [m.text for m in entry.findall('./static/member')]
pprint.pprint(data_by_entry)
```

output

```
{'TBR1': ['TBR1-1.1.1.1_21',
          'TBR2-2.2.2.2_24',
          'TBR3-3.3.3.3_21',
          'TBR4-4.4.4.4_24'],
 'TBR2': ['TBR1-4.1.1.1_21',
          'TBR2-4.2.2.2_24',
          'TBR3-4.3.3.3_21',
          'TBR4-9.4.4.4_24']}
```

Answer (score 0):

The source of your problem is that:

- within `for mem in ip.findall('member'):` loop *mem* is the current *member* element,
- but the first instruction in this loop is `member = mem.find('member')`,
  so you attempt to find **another** (nested) member within the current *member*,
  which doesn't exist.

Another flaw in your code is that there is no point in printing a node which does
not have any text.

Change your loop to the code below:

```
for entries in root.findall('entry'):
    name = entries.get('name')
    print(name)
    ip = entries.find('static')
    print('Members:')
    for mem in ip.findall('member'):
        print(mem.text)
```

and you will get meaningful result.